# How to make a 'makefile' in c

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile

I can't understand how I can produce a makefile for C code

I have the following .c file which normally I execute in the following manner:

```
gcc server.c -o server.out -lpthread
```

Once compiled, I run the .out file like this:

```
./server.out 4000
```

EDITED

I only need the make files to compile the program rather than running it too..

Comment: So you want to write a C program that creates Makefiles?

Comment: @H2co3 .. actually what i need is to make a make file for the latter c program i created... (i.e. to run the server.c program)

Comment: @DigitalDa .. sorry my post was not clear... i'll edit it to make it more legible.. i need it just to compile it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If naming your executable file `server` will do for you, then just

```
LDLIBS=-lpthread
all: server
```

in a file called `Makefile` will do. The you can just type

```
make
```

to build it.

Ortherwise your `Makefile` should contain:

```
server.out: server.c
        gcc server.c -o server.out -lpthread
```

Except that it is a tabulation, **not spaces** before the text “`gcc`”.

Answer (score 2):

To start , you can create a project in eclipse and it would create a makefile for you. And then you can start going into the details about what all is added and this can trim out things you understand are not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/ChrisLundquist/OpenCL-Compiler/blob/master/Makefile

Is an example of a simple make file.